# How to give a 2D structure 3D depth

Tags: opengl

I am begging to learn OpenGL as part of a molecular modeling project, and currently I am trying to render 7 helices that will be placed spatially close to each other and will move, tilt and interact with each other in certain ways. My question is how to give the 2D scene 3-Dimensional depth so that the geometric structures look like true helices in three dimensions?

I have tried playing around with projection matrices (gulPerspective, glFrustum) without much luck, as well as using the glDepthRange function.

I include my code for rendering the helices, but for simplicity I insert the code for rendering one helix (the other 6 helices are exactly the same except for their translation matrix and the color function parameters) and for reshaping when mapping from object coordinates to clip coordinates:

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
void init() {

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);    // Black background
    glLineWidth(8.0);

}

/* CALLED TO DRAW THE HELICES */ 

void RenderHelix() {

    GLfloat x,y,z; 
    GLfloat c = 2.5f;   //helical pitch 
    GLfloat theta;      //constant angle between tangent and x-axis 
    GLfloat r = 4.5f;   //radius 
    //GLint i = 1;      //loop through code to render 7 helices 

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

/* GREEN HELIX */ 

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); 
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);           
    for(theta = 0; theta <= 360; ++theta) { 
        x = r*(cos(theta));
        y = r*(sin(theta));
        z = c*theta; 
        glVertex3f(x,y,z);
    }
    glEnd();
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    glScalef(1.0,1.0,12.0); 
    glTranslatef(50.0, 100.0, 0.0);  //Move Position 
    glRotatef(90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

/* Other 6 helices .... */

glFlush(); 
 glutSwapBuffers();

}

void Reshape(GLint w, GLint h) {

    if(h==0)
        h=1;

    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    GLfloat aspectratio = (GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h;
    if(w<=h)
        glOrtho(-100,100,-100/aspectratio,100/aspectratio, -100,310);
    else
        glOrtho(-100*aspectratio,100*aspectratio,-100,100,-100,310);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glLoadIdentity();       
}
```

Comment: Please, correct your code formatting.

Comment: Did you glEnable(GL_DEPTHTEST); ?

Comment: I had not included it in fact, but I did now. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code and put a comment here and there:

```
void init() {
    /* One time OpenGL initialization would be textures and
     * other static stuff. Nothing like that here */    
}

/* CALLED TO DRAW THE HELICES */ 

void RenderHelix() {

    GLfloat x,y,z; 
    float aspectratio;
    GLfloat c = 2.5f;   //helical pitch 
    GLfloat theta;      //constant angle between tangent and x-axis 
    GLfloat r = 4.5f;   //radius 
    //GLint i = 1;      //loop through code to render 7 helices 

    /* assuming w and h are globals or somehow else accessible */
    aspectratio = (float)w/(float)h;
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);    // Black background
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    GLfloat aspectratio = (GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h;
    if(w<=h)
        glFrustum(-10.f,10.f, -10.f/aspectratio, 10.f/aspectratio, 1.0f, 10.f);
    else
        glFrustum(-10.f*aspectratio,10.f*aspectratio,-10.f,10.f, 1.0f,10.f);

/* enable depth testing, also make sure the right depth func is used */
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);


/* GREEN HELIX */ 
    glLineWidth(8.0);    

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0.f, 0.f, -4.5f);

    glPushMatrix();
    /* this helix will be drawn in the center, as it's not moved anywhere. */

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); 
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    /* trigonometric functions take radians, not degrees */
    for(theta = 0; theta <= M_PI2; theta += M_PI2*0.01;) { 
        /* instead of calculating the helices a new each rendering
         * pass you should store them to a vertex array. */
        x = r*cosf(theta);
        y = r*sinf(theta);
        z = c*theta; 
        glVertex3f(x,y,z);
    }
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();

/* Other 6 helices .... */
    glScalef(1.0,1.0,12.0); 
    glTranslatef(50.0, 100.0, 0.0);  //Move Position of next helix, you may want to use glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix
    glRotatef(90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);  // a null rotation, what's that's supposed to do?


glFlush(); // redundant, glFlush is implied by SwapBuffers
 glutSwapBuffers();

}

void Reshape(GLint w, GLint h) {
    /* Pleast don't set OpenGL stuff in the window reshape handler.
     * This just causes confusion, as soon one uses multiple projections
     * in a single rendering */
}
```

Comment: Thank very much you for your corrections, I tried them and my output looks better although I think that glFrustum parameters still require some fine-tuning. Could I ask the following: if I were to store each helix separateley in an array of vertices could I then apply rotations/translations/scalings so that the helices themselves (each stored in one array) could tilt, spin (rotate about their own axis) and generally assume desired spatial arrangements? I hope this question is not too vague. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Spyros, the way to do individual transformations on particular objects is to use the matrix stack. For each object, call glPushMatrix(), do whatever transformations you need for that particular object, render it, then call glPopMatrix() to return to the prior state. You can even use several layers on the stack to create sub-objects to an object (i.e. to atoms in a molecule, or moons around a planet, relative to the central object's orientation and position).